# how to record screen with ffmpeg by intel-Atom using gpu

Tags: linux, windows, ffmpeg, intel

I'm in arch-like distribution called void-Linux

perhaps `qsv` used to recording screen with GPU in intel `Atom-CPU in your

but, I can't success recording my screen with `qsv` encoder yet
this is my script

```sh
ffmpeg \
    -f x11grab             \
    -y                     \
    -video_size 1280x800   \
    -framerate 60          \
    -i :0                  \
    -vcodec libx264        \
    -preset ultrafast      \
    -qp 0                  \
    -pix_fmt yuv444p       \
     output.mkv
```

[how to compile qsv in ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/feedsbrain/0191516b5625b577c2b14241cff4fe30)

Comment: No errors? No log?

Comment: this command is work but, I want to use GPU not a CPU encoder

Comment: See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync